# Remove duplicates from loop

Tags: ruby

i have following code.

```
for i in 0..sold.length-1
    duplicate = sold[i]
    print duplicate.check_duplicates
    print "     "
    print sold[i].lotnumber + "\t"

    print sold[i].serialnumber

end
```

this will print

```
 1     29371    43
 1     13797    6
 1     08114    55
 1     70657    106
 1     32741    74
 2     07272    103
 2     07272    103
 1     37416    14
 1     05153    177
 1     54338    115
 3     74522    171
 3     74522    171
 3     74522    171
```

How can i remove the duplicates (3     74522    171 and 2     07272 103) so there is only 1 of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash resulting from the [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method can be used as a counting device; this does not use the `check_duplicates` method.

```
grouped = sold.group_by{|item| [item.lotnumber, item.serialnumber]}
grouped.each{|key, value| puts "#{value.size}   #{key.first}\t#{key.last}"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uniq_solds = sold.collect{|s| [s.check_duplicates, s.lotnumber, s.serialnumber]}.uniq

uniq_solds.each do |s|
  p s.join("      ")
end
```

Comment: The second part could also be `puts uniq_solds.map{|s| s.join("     ")}`

Comment: i get following error: undefined method duplicate' for #<Lottery:0x007f8b2087ef58> (NoMethodError) from sved.rb:81:in collect' from sved.rb:81:in `<main>'

Comment: That was a mistake. Modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something called uniq!, here is a link to the API.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21

---

Comment: `uniq!` does not provide the numbers of duplicates (`print duplicate.check_duplicates`).