# Store data from hash to array

Tags: ruby

I have a array called `sold` where all the serial and lottery numbers are stored. This takes the array, prints how many of the identical elements are in the array, and stores them in a hash:

```
grouped = sold.group_by{|item| [item.lotnumber, item.serialnumber]}
grouped.each {|key, value| fh.puts "  #{value.size}\t    #{key.first}\t     #{key.last}"}
```

How can I store all the `#{value.size}` in an array?

Comment: forget that i have removed it.

Comment: Give some examples for better understanding..

Comment: @mbratch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203452/remove-duplicates-from-loop/20204197#20204197

Answer (score 0):

```
value_size_array = grouped.collect{|key, value| value.size}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a straight-up array of sizes:

```
grouped.values.collect(&:size)
```

If all you want is the totals, you can probably do it a different way:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
sold.each do |item|
  counts[[item.lotnumber, item.serialnumber]] += 1
end
```