# Count duplicates in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, duplicates

```
sold = Array.new

ticketfile.each {|line| 
    a = line.split(",")

    nr2 = Ticket.new(a[0],a[1])
    sold<<nr2

}
```

This is my array where i have following elements: ticknum and serialnum.
It gets these information from a text file.

What i want is to find all duplicates (where ticknum and serialnum are identical) and make a new array where ticknum, serialnum, and amount of duplicates are.

Anyone who can help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest going with very simple solution:

```
ticketfile.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|line, hash| 
  hash[line.split(",")] += 1
}
```

You could define `eql?` method on your `Ticket` class to use it as a key in hash (see [Which equality test does Ruby's Hash use when comparing keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247000/which-equality-test-does-rubys-hash-use-when-comparing-keys))

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

#### Emulating your `Ticket` `class`:

```
class Ticket < Struct.new(:ticknum, :serialnum); end
=> nil
```

#### Create some tickets:

(This is just emulating your file read into an `Array`)

```
tickets = [Ticket.new(1, 2), Ticket.new(1, 2), Ticket.new(1, 3), Ticket.new(1, 4), Ticket.new(1, 4)]
=> [#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>,
 #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>,
 #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=3>,
 #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>,
 #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>]
```

#### Here's a [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
groups = tickets.group_by { |t| [t.ticknum, t.serialnum] }
=> {[1, 2]=>
  [#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>,
   #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>],
 [1, 3]=>[#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=3>],
 [1, 4]=>
  [#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>,
   #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>]}
```

#### Filter out non-duplicates:

```
duplicates = groups.reject { |k, v| v.length < 2 }
=> {[1, 2]=>
  [#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>,
   #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>],
 [1, 4]=>
  [#<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>,
   #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>]}
```

#### Listing the number of times each duplicated `Ticket` appears:

```
duplicates.values.each do | group |
  puts "There are #{group.length} of #{group.first}"
end  
There are 2 of #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=2>
There are 2 of #<struct Ticket ticknum=1, serialnum=4>
```

Comment: OP has been answered this before...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203452/remove-duplicates-from-loop/20204197#20204197